# Calculating different number of vehicles that a number of wheels can have

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

Given n, the total number of wheels there are, how many different ways can there be 2 and 4 wheeled vehicles? A way is different if and only if the number of 2 wheeled vehicles and 4 wheeled vehicles is different from any other way. All wheels must be used, no wheel can be left behind

Some examples:

```
4 Wheels:  2 -> 2,2 and 4   i.e. you can have two 2-wheeled vehicles or one 4-wheeled vehicle
6 Wheels:  2 -> 2,2,2 and 4,2
10 Wheels: 3 -> 2,2,2,2,2; 2,2,2,4; 2,4,4
```

I did that problem as such, but I know that it doesn't count the different ways, but rather it counts the different ordering of the vehicles as well. Here is my code:

```
memo = {2:1, 4:2}
def uniqueCount(wheels, memo):
    if wheels%2 == 1:
        return 0
    if memo.get(wheels, 0) != 0:
        return memo[wheels]
    val = uniqueCounts(wheels -2, memo) + uniqueCounts(wheels - 4, memo)
    memo[wheels] = val
    return val
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to branch in your recursion to two different paths, one that can only add 4-wheelers, or jump to the other branch - one that can only add 2-wheelers. This way you will never have the same solution with different orderings.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and add the expected output of 6, 8, 10, 12 wheels besides the 2 and 4 in the code. This way it'd be easier for others to figure out what the problem really is.

Comment: Can you give an example? What would be the expected answer for 10?

Comment: Added a few examples. Thank you for your help

Comment: You don't need to use recursion. Imagine the wheels are positioned in a row and there's a divider. All wheels to the left of the divider go to 4-wheelers, and the rest to 2-wheelers. Obviously the divider can only be positioned at k*4 for some k. The position of the divider uniquely identifies a split. The number of possible positions is left to the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code correctly starts by "rejecting" any odd input. However, for the remaining part, there is no need for memoization or recursion. When the input is even, the number of possibilities is directly determined by the number of 4-wheel cars you can get from the input number.

Let's say the input is 22, then the number of 4s you can get from that is 22//4 = 5. This corresponds to the following combinations:

```
4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
4 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
4 4 4 2 2 2 2 2
4 4 4 4 2 2 2
4 4 4 4 4 2
```

There is one more combination that should be counted, which is the one without any 4:

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

So in general the solution is n//4 + 1

```
def uniqueCount(wheels):
    if wheels % 2 == 1:
        return 0
    return wheels // 4 + 1
```